# Mass remove lines in Magento product descriptions

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a magento store with over 6000 products.

Basically i have set up a new site and transferred the products across but in all the descriptions there is the company name from the old site and contact numbers. I am wanting to delete or replace all the text containing the previous website name and number from product descriptions.

At first i thought i could export all the products to a csv and use 'find & replace' in openoffice, but with there being so many products it times out on export in Magento.

I am sure its a problem that people have had in the past but i have no clue on how to do this.

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve this: magento way and through sql queries. 
For the magento way you want to collect all products, foreach over the items, setDescription() and save() inside the loop.

I would recommend using the sql way:

**Step 1)** Find the attribute_id of the product attribute *description* and note it down:

```
SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = "description" and entity_type_id = 4; # 4 equals catalog_product
```

**Step 2)** Replace the old value "CompanyOld" with the new one "CompanyNew" for all description attributes of all products:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_text SET value = REPLACE(value,'CompanyOld','CompanyNew') WHERE value LIKE '%CompanyOld%' AND attribute_id=attributeIdFromAboveQuery;
```